# Doctrine - QueryBuilder: verify if query returns results (Count)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query which in two stages:

```
public function findOtherRosters($user){
    $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                ->addSelect('m')
            ->where('m.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user);
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
    $qb
        ->where('ro not IN (:rosters)')
            ->setParameter('rosters', $q2->getQuery()->getResult())
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I need to check if the first query ($qb) returns results. If result I run a query, if not another query. At the moment my code is as followed:

```
public function findOtherRosters($user){
    $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                ->addSelect('m')
            ->where('m.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user);

    if ( is_null($q2) ){ // the issue is here
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
        $qb
            ->where ('ro not IN (:rosters)')
                ->setParameter('rosters', $q2->getQuery()->getResult())
        ;

    } else {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

The issue is with the is_null ; I need to check if the first query returns any lines not if is null.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your intention here but shouldn't you `getResult()` first in order to check that?

Somthing like this?

```
public function findOtherRosters($user){
    $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                ->addSelect('m')
            ->where('m.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user);

    $q2Result = $q2->getQuery()->getResult(); // <<---- THIS

    if ( count($q2Result) ){ // the issue is here <<--- THIS
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
        $qb
            ->where ('ro not IN (:rosters)')
                ->setParameter('rosters', $q2Result) // <<---- THIS
        ;

    } else {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Yes; I should have get the result first. Thanks a lot!